# Connect to Azure Storage Account using only SAS token?

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

Is there a way to connect to a storage account or container only using a SAS token and the endpoint for that storage account? I’ve already done the demo/sample and it is using the connection string (which works) but I don’t see how to connect to my storage using only the SAS?
Is there any example how to do this in java?

Comment: Here is the code sample for C#, Java should be something similar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#using-a-sas-in-a-constructor-or-method

Comment: The follwoing documentation might helps in your scenario:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage-test/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/SasTests.java

Comment: @Jim Hi,any progress now? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generate SAS Token for my specific blob on the portal then download it successfully via the token.

[image]

***sample code:***

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

public class DownloadBlobSAS {

    public static final String blobSasToken = "***";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CloudBlockBlob sasBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new URI(blobSasToken));

            InputStream input =  sasBlob.openInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
            String utf8str = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(inr);
            System.out.println(utf8str);

            System.out.println("print done");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***Output Result:***

[image]

If you want to generate SAS token, you need to provide connection string first to access container or blob.

Then you could use `generateSharedAccessSignature()` method to create SAS token.You could refer to the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage-test/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/SasTests.java#L409):

```
SharedAccessBlobPolicy sp = createSharedAccessPolicy(
                EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.LIST), 300);
        BlobContainerPermissions perms = new BlobContainerPermissions();

        perms.getSharedAccessPolicies().put("readperm", sp);
        this.container.uploadPermissions(perms);
        Thread.sleep(30000);

        CloudBlockBlob sasBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new URI(this.blob.getUri().toString() + "?"
                + this.blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(null, "readperm")));
```

Hope it helps you.